Y2038 problem still exists under 64bit Windows+PHP8 environment
system cfg: 64bit notebook with 64bit Win11 Home Edition (x64 MSVC runtime installed) and the latest 64bit PHP8.3.8.
After I manually set system time to 2040-01-01, I can't get the "current time" correctly by using time() or datetime::getTimestamp(), both result in (same) negative numbers. But, all other functions about date and time are working normally, for example, strtotime("2040-01-01") outputs the correct integer value bigger than 2^31.
My question is: Did I miss something in my system's configuration? Or, it's just a "bug" of microsoft windows? I've heard that Linux doesn't have such kind of problem, but I am sorry I am not familiar with Linux...
Thanks advance for any of your anwsers!!
I've tried running/debugging PHP from VS Code(64bit) or just command line but got the same result. I just eager to know whether I did something wrong or some other reasons.
update20240703: I've managed to install a Ubantu VM......yes, it works:
screenshot of time()&date()
update20240711: the current PHP installation pack is named php-8.3.8-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.exe, which means it was compiled upon visualstudio2019, which is delivered as a Win32 program only. While the latest VS2022 (launched a few days ago) was built for multiple architectures(x86/x64/arm). I installed VS2022 today (with C++ support only) and run the similar time test, it gets the correct "current timestamp" beyond 2038.
So, probable solution of this question is:

just waiting for a new official build of PHP by using of VS17 or later
Self-build PHP from open-source code under VS2022(x64) environment or by using Mingw64 for windows.


the current PHP installation pack is named php-8.3.8-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.exe, which means it was compiled upon visualstudio2019, which is delivered as a Win32 program only. While the latest VS2022 (launched a few days ago) was built for multiple architectures(x86/x64/arm). I installed VS2022 today (with C++ support only) and run the similar time test, it gets the correct "current timestamp" beyond 2038.
So, probable solution of this question is:

just waiting for a new official build of PHP by using of VS17 or later
Self-build PHP from open-source code under VS2022(x64) environment or by using Mingw64 for windows.


While browsing the source code of PHP8.3.10, I've found that the Time.c & Time.h are located in the directory which named "win32"......
